# How to elimnate a compiler Warning "AppDelegate does not implement the NSTextView protocol"

Tags: cocoa

I have a `NStextView` defined in a UI built with IB. I have in my AppDelegate.m file the following to know when the text is changed in the textView.

```
- (void)textDidChange:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
}
```

Everything works but, the compiler is warning that my controller, "WinKeyer2AppDelegate" does not implement the `NSTextView` delegate protocol.

I have researched the issue and the suggestion is to add the protocol declaration to my class interface definition. I have no class interface definition for the textView set up in IB. There is a "delegate" connection in the textView Connections Inspector but what do I connect it to, WinKeyer2AppDelegate does not work and I have no reference to an `NSText` object which lists the `textDidChange:` item in its protocol reference. I attempted add an NSText object to my .xib and connect it to "delegate" but that did not help either.

Answer (score 2):

You need to your interface definition of WinKeyer2AppDelegate to include NSTextViewDelegate.

For example: `@interface WinKeyer2AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplictionDelegate, NSTextViewDelegate>`